# Change color for percentage bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

A percentage bar was made by `ggplot2`, `fill=cyl` created the default color (red/green/blue) for the bar. How can I change the color? Any ideas?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = pct, fill=cyl, label = scales::percent(pct))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/necyX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2`s `scale_fill_manual` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = pct, fill=cyl, label = scales::percent(pct))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#555555", "#554325", "#122355"))
```

We can use hex values for colors or names, i.e. something like

```
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "black", "red"))
```

is also possible